# How to remove [' '] from a string variable

Tags: python

Opening a text file for a save 1 = yes 0 = no. So i wanted python to read line 1 and set a variable to that. The variable comes out with

> ['1\n']

I only wanted the "1" so I managed to remove the \n with the line of code

```
played=[i.replace("\n", "") for i in played ]
played=[i.replace("['", "") for i in played ]
played=[i.replace("']", "") for i in played ]
```

but i still came out with

> ['1']

Does anyone know a way to remove the square brackets and single speech marks
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's actually a list. You can get that element out with this:

```
played=int(played[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to an integer with an `int` cast and access the first item:

```
played=[int(i.replace("\n", "")) for i in played ][0]
```

---

```
>>> played = ["1\n"]
>>> played=[int(i.replace("\n", "")) for i in played ][0]
>>> played
1
>>>
```